# xlookup on filtered range

Tags: excel, vba, formula, xlookup

I am new in VBA and would like to write a code which fills cells with xlookup formula.

I have 2 tables on different sheets but in the same workbook:

1. on "New TS" sheet, I need to filter for the TBD-s in col H, and replace them with the exact value based on the data on the "Old TS" sheet.
2. formula should to be used in the filtered range: **=XLOOKUP(1, ('New TS'!C4='Old TS'!C2:C35) * ('New TS'!E4='Old TS'!E2:E35),'Old TS'!G2:G35,"TBD",0)**
3. C4 and E4 can change based on which row contains the first TBD
4. Last row (now 35) can change based on the table on the Old TS sheet.

I would highly appreciate if you could help me how to add that to my code.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New TS").range("1:1").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="TBD"
endrow2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Old TS").range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
firstrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New TS").range("H2:H" & Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells().Row
                                                

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New TS").Cells(firstrow, 8) = Application.XLookup(1, (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New TS").range(firstrow, 3) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Old TS").range("C2:C" & endrow2)) * (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New TS").range(firstrow, 5) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Old TS").range("E2:E" & endrow2)), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Old TS").range("G2:G" & endrow2), "TBD", 0)
```

Please let me know if you need more information about that.

Comment: Do you want to add the formula itself to the cells, or the resulting value of the formula to the cells?

Comment: It would be better to get the exact values instead of the formula

Comment: If possible, please add some sample data to your post for testing.

Comment: Also, does the code you have posted work or does it produce an error? Or not the results you want?

Comment: I have uploaded some screenshots with a quick description as new answer.Please see below.

Answer (score 0):

I've never been able to get the `XLOOKUP` working in the same way as the formula when you have multiple criteria, as in your case.

My own implementation doesn't have to filter the range at all, just look for rows containing `TBD`.

The other "trick" to the example solution here is in how you find a "matching" row. Your criteria is essentially a combination of data from two columns. Assuming that this combination is always unique, the solution is ideal for a `Dictionary`. Each "key" to a [dictionary](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/) entry is this unique combination of the two values.

(Another technique in the example below creates [memory-based arrays from the worksheet range](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/#Reading_from_a_Range_to_the_VBA_Array) to speed processing.)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ReplaceTBDValues()
    '--- capture the data into memory-based arrays
    Dim newTSArea As Range
    Dim newTS As Variant
    Set newTSArea = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New TS").UsedRange
    newTS = newTSArea.Value
    
    Dim oldTSArea As Range
    Dim oldTS As Variant
    Set oldTSArea = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Old TS").UsedRange
    oldTS = oldTSArea.Value
    
    '--- create a Dictionary of the OldTS values for quick lookup
    '    the "key" for quick lookup is a combination of the values
    '    in columns C and E
    Dim oldTSDict As Dictionary
    Set oldTSDict = New Dictionary
    
    Const NUMBER_COL As Long = 3
    Const GROUP2_COL As Long = 5
    Const OLD_TITLE_COL As Long = 8
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To UBound(oldTS, 1) 'skip the header row
        Dim tsKey As String
        tsKey = oldTS(i, NUMBER_COL) & oldTS(i, GROUP2_COL)
        If Not oldTSDict.Exists(tsKey) Then
            '--- store the row number in the dictionary
            oldTSDict.Add tsKey, i
        Else
            Debug.Print "Duplicate C/E values in row " & i & "!"
        End If
    Next i
    
    '--- now run through the lines in New TS and replace the TBD data
    For i = 2 To UBound(newTS, 1)    'skip the header row
        If newTS(i, OLD_TITLE_COL) = "TBD" Then
            Dim checkKey As String
            checkKey = newTS(i, NUMBER_COL) & newTS(i, GROUP2_COL)
            If oldTSDict.Exists(checkKey) Then
                '--- found the values, so replace
                newTS(i, OLD_TITLE_COL) = oldTS(oldTSDict(checkKey), OLD_TITLE_COL)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
    '--- finally copy the array back to the New TS sheet
    newTSArea.Value = newTS
End Sub
```